# How to call a jQuery function which in same project but different folder in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, razor, view, scope, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to call a function say **LinkWallet**() from a function named **CustomerNew**()

**LinkWallet**() is in file named **WalletDetails**.**cshtml** while **CustomerNew**() is in file named **Create**.**cshtml**

The problem is that while both these files are in same project, they are in different folders under MVC's Views section.

**Create**.**cshtml** is in **Views/Customer/Create.cshtml**

**WalletDetails**.**cshtml** is in **Views/CustomerWallet/WalletDetails.cshtm**l

How can I call stated function from one class to anther? I don't to rewrite and googling didn't help.

Comment: the best you can do is make it helper method that you can call anywhere you want.

Answer (score 5):

To do so, You need to put all your JS and jQuery functions in the same external file that you put in your scripts folder. After that, you can reference that file to your views by adding the script tag to your view or _Layout.cshtml file like this:

```
<script src="~/scripts/YOURSCRIPTFILENAME.js"></script>
```

or by using the scripts.rendering with razor like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/YOURSCRIPTFILENAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not call for views, but for actions! for calling an action from different controller you just need to call proper url for it.
for example if you want to call action WalletDetails from controller CustomerWallet , your url in jquery load function or ajax get function should be 
/CustomerWallet/WalletDetails/{id}.